# How do I make an html5 animation when a button is clicked on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

I have an idea for an interactive animation that I would like to create in html5. I want to have a soccer field with jerseys on it in a formation like 4-4-2 and have different options on the side to change the formation let's say to a 4-5-1 and then when this button is clicked that says 4-5-1 the jersey will rearrange on the field to that shape. 
Any ideas on how I could do this ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most dependency-free way to do so would be to add a JavaScript function to the **onClick** attribute of your button or element, and then have JavaScript move the players around by editing their positions, attributes, and so forth.

However, I would recommend using jQuery since it's generally easier. You would then bind an action to the button's id (id="..." attribute on your ). For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("mybuttonid").click(function(event){
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Would this create the effect of them moving across the field and rearranging or would it just jump to them in the new spots

Comment: It will just jump them. Transitioning elements will require another library. There are many tools for doing smooth transitions very easily, and almost every single one works with jQuery. However, I'm no expert on them.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/3YRzS/

like mentioned, jquery and animate.

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible on certain browsers with the CSS3 Key Frames animations, as seen on the smashing magazine's website, for example - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/